# Mongoose model middleware post is throwing type error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to delete all 'Shifts' related to 'Event', this code throws this error in VSCode:

> No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following
> error.
> Argument of type '"remove"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.

And this on next() function:

> This expression is not callable.
>
> Type 'NativeError' has no call signatures.

```js
const eventSchema = new Schema<EventInterface>({
  userId: { 
    type: String,
    required: true 
  },
  studio: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Studio'
  },
  shifts: [{ 
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Shift'
  }],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  class: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Class',
    required: true
  },
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false
});

// Middleware to handle post-remove event
eventSchema.post<EventInterface>('remove', { document: true }, async function (next) {
  const event = this;
  const Shift = model('Shift');

  try {
    // Delete all related Shift documents
    await Shift.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: event.shifts } });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [PR](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/13306):

> because for 7.0 the `.remove()` function was just renamed `.deleteOne()`

And this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/13518):

> `remove()` was deprecated in a previous version, and removed in Mongoose 7. So this is expected.

They should update the documentation.

The solution is to use the `deleteOne` document middleware.

E.g.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

interface EventInterface {
    userId: string;
    shifts: any[];
}
const shiftSchema = new mongoose.Schema();
const Shift = mongoose.model('Shift', shiftSchema);

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema<EventInterface>({
    userId: String,
    shifts: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Shift',
        },
    ],
});

eventSchema.post<EventInterface>('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }, async function (doc, next) {
    const event = this;
    const Shift = mongoose.model('Shift');
    console.log('doc:', doc, doc instanceof Event);
    console.log('this:', this, this === doc);
    try {
        await Shift.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: event.shifts } });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

(async function main() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        // seed
        const [s1, s2] = await Shift.create([{}, {}]);
        const [e] = await Event.create([{ userId: '1', shifts: [s1, s2] }]);

        await e?.deleteOne();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```bash
7.3.2
Mongoose: shifts.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d23"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: shifts.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d24"), __v: 0 }, {})
Mongoose: events.insertOne({ userId: '1', shifts: [ ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d23"), ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d24") ], _id: ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d27"), __v: 0}, {})
Mongoose: events.deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d27") }, { session: null })
doc: {
  userId: '1',
  shifts: [
    { _id: new ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d23"), __v: 0 },
    { _id: new ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d24"), __v: 0 }
  ],
  _id: new ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d27"),
  __v: 0
} true
this: {
  userId: '1',
  shifts: [
    { _id: new ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d23"), __v: 0 },
    { _id: new ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d24"), __v: 0 }
  ],
  _id: new ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d27"),
  __v: 0
} true
Mongoose: shifts.deleteMany({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d23"), ObjectId("64b0d22b22fff59262045d24") ] }}, {})
```

As you can see, when you call the `event.deleteOne()` method, it will trigger the post hook of the `deleteOne` middleware.

Comment: Thanks, it works!. What if i have the same situation with Shifts documents? for example i would like to remove all related documents to Shifts. Then when i delete an Event, it should remove all related Shifts, and then must remove all another related to Shifts documents. How can i do that?.

Comment: @sonEtLumiere Sorry, I don't understand your question. If this is a new question, you should post a new question with details.